# Using junit build base unit tests and abstract validation

Tags: java, inheritance, junit, java-8

Assume that I am building a monthly subscription charging feature for a mobile app, there are multiple ways to charge the bill. It can be through Apple Pay, Google wallet, paypal, visa/master depends on the platform. Each provider has their own implementation and respective JUnit tests ( as they are using Java).

To evaluate few basic functionalities, there are few cases which every implementation has to validate. So, the plan is to write base tests and call an abstract validate method.

Here is my approach,

```
public abstract class BaseBillingTest 
{
 public abstract BillCharger getBillCharger();
 public abstract void ValidateTest1(Bill input, Bill output); 
 public void tests_case_1(){
  Bill input = new Bill(<some value>);
  Bill Output = getBillCharger().charge(input);
  ValidateTest1(input, output);
 }
}
```

Any derived test class will implement the abstract methods, so it has the responsibility to implement the validate methods. The derived test class need not know what is happening in the base test, as they can just validate the output based on the input.

Any suggestions to approach this in a more elegant fashion ? Are there any design patterns which I can apply in this scenario ?

Comment: As you can see in comments in one of the answers, we are unable to agree which approach better fits your needs. You could help us by explaining why you are looking for an alternative approach, i.e., why are you dissatisfied with your own solution? You seem to have achieved a good level of separation of concerns, so: what is lacking?

Answer (score 2):

Your example of Inheritance in my opinion is not the optimal way to go for the two abstract methods. One is Constructional and the other is static - you validate one Bill against another.

In both cases inheritance is not the correct relationship here.  You can use successfully Factory pattern for the "getBillCharger" or the more modern TestDataBuilders or ObjectMother pattern.

For the second method you can just use a helper class.
If you need to invoke the same construction logic several times in a Test class you can use @Before

One important aspect is that if you place your tests_case_1 in super class you will be hiding parts of your logic and your tests will not be that obvious. I prefer more explicit and visible test cases therefore I would avoid this kind of setup.

Comment: "inheritance is not the correct relationship here" will not find a judge to say true or false, because there's no law prohibiting the use of inheritance. From a pragmatic p.o.v. investing more than one design pattern may be undesirable, in this regard the inheritance based solution is even simpler - it may just not be "modern". Never asses a question of methodology without putting your criteria on the table: what's gained? what's sacrificed? -- What is elegance in code? Frankly, I can see no deficit in the original solution, nice separation of concerns, so in which direction should we improve?

Comment: @StephanHerrmann Do you need to inherit a house in order to use its bathroom :) Also read carefuly my post, I am not saying that a particular pattern should be used. Plain factory, or builder is fine.

Comment: Using the word "inheritance" was introduced in order to help intuition, not in order to put your brain into a jail :)) Every metaphor has its limits, technical design shouldn't suffer from those limits.

Comment: I still think that the chances of code smell with inheritance are higher than the chances of code smell without inheritance irrespectively if there are some cases when it is fine. Without knowing in details his @raghavankl use case I would bet on not using inheritance.

Comment: If hand-waving about "chances of code smells" is all we are exchanging, then we should probably close the question as opinion based. I see little technical merit in this discussion.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann I don't think the question is opinion based but i don't have the desire to enter the discussion I feel you are pulling towards. You have posted your opinion, if people like it you will recieve up votes.

Answer (score 0):

The original approach does, in fact, apply a design pattern, it's called [Template Method](http://BTW,%20this%20approach%20_does_%20apply%20a%20design%20pattern:%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

OTOH, the questions has a slight smell of hunting for design patterns as a goal in its own right. Why bother, if they already have a solution at hand that fulfills functional (here: testing the right thing) as well as non-functional (here: clearly separating common parts from specifics) requirements. The one reason I would accept is: communication, as in: being able to give a name to the design so that co-workers quickly understand my intentions.